# Streaming media through amzon server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, video-streaming

I hosted my application in amazon,creating an ec2 instance and in that using apachae tomcat server ,i hosted my application. Ec2 Instance i created is t1.micro. This application used to play video in browser.But the video plays with interruptions in between.How can i improve the performance of the video played?
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the quality specs of your video?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **use a larger instance**.

Most likely you're running out of bandwidth. Different instance types have different network capacity. If you move from a micro to a small you'll find you have more bandwidth available. If the video plays with less or no interruptions then most likely it's a bandwidth issue.

*I'm assuming that you're not performing any transcoding etc*